# When the laptop lid closes and I lift it back up, keyboard won't work

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, keyboard

When the laptop lid closes and I lift it back up, keyboard won't work.

Due to being on the road traveling, I'm using an old Asus from 2013, and I am using Win 8. I just updated to 8.1, but I don't want to test it because then I'll have to restart just to get my keyboard back.

We had to reformat the laptop b/c while running Win 10, it was soooo slow, I couldn't do anything with it.

Thanks